# This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after moving forward is not supported

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-db, zend-framework3

i want to iterate à table to view tables data 2 time (in listbox and dropdown boutton), when i use one foreach for 1 inout it's ok, but when i use 2 foreach for 2 inputs i hade the bellow error i searched, i found that i must use $resultSet->buffer(); whn i replace it it my table the same eror stay:

File:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result.php:182
Message:
This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after moving forward is not supported
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-db\src\ResultSet\AbstractResultSet.php(241): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result->rewind()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\module\Documentachat\view\documentachat\documentachat\index.phtml(138): Zend\Db\ResultSet\AbstractResultSet->rewind()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(506): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\View.php(207): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(NULL)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\View.php(236): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-view\src\View.php(200): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(105): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(248): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(384): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(356): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-commercial-03\public\index.php(29): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#13 {main}
```

Table :

```
<?php
///=======================DocumentachatTable factory=========================
namespace Documentachat\Model;

use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;

class DocumentachatTable
{
    protected $tableGateway;
    private $lastinserted;

    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll($paginated = false)
    {

        if ($paginated) {

            // create a new Select object for the table album
            $select = new Select('achat__document');
            // create a new result set based on the Album entity
            $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
            $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Documentachat());
            // create a new pagination adapter object
            $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect(
            // our configured select object
                $select,
                // the adapter to run it against
                $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(),
                // the result set to hydrate
        $resultSetPrototype->buffer();
                $resultSetPrototype
            );
            $select->where(array('achat__document.deleted' => 1));
            $paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);

            return $paginator;
        }

        $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
        $select->where(array('achat__document.deleted' => 1));
        $results = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        return $results;

    }

    public function lastInserted()
    {
        return $this->lastinserted;
    }

    public function getDocument($id)
    {
        $id = (int)$id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row) {
            throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row;
    }

    public function getLastCount($idType)
    {
        $idType = (int)$idType;
        $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

        $select->where->equalTo('id_type', $idType);
        $select->order('count desc');

        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $row;
    }

    public function saveDocument(Documentachat $document)
    {
        $data = array(
            'reference' => $document->reference,
            'id_type' => $document->idType,
            'id_fournisseur' => $document->idFournisseur,
            'address' => $document->address,
            'deleted' => 1,
            'date_doc' => $document->dateDoc
        );

        $id = (int)$document->id;
        if ($id == 0) {
            $data['count'] = $this->getLastCount($document->idType)->count + 1;
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
            $this->lastinserted = $this->tableGateway->getLastInsertValue();
        } else {
            if ($this->getDocument($id)) {
                $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Documentachat id does not exist');
            }
        }
    }

    public function deleteDocument($id)
    {
        $data = array(
            'deleted' => 0,
        );
        $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
    }

    public function searchDocument($query)
    {
        $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
        $select->where(array('achat__document.deleted' => 1));
        $select->where->like('achat__document.reference', '%' . $query . '%');
        $results = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
        return $results;
    }
```

View:

```
<?php

$title = 'Documentachat';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>




<div class="container-fluid container-fullw bg-white ng-scope">

<!--    ======partie haut-->

        <div class="panel border-dark   panel-white bg-white margin-top-20"  style="box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%), 0 3px 6px rgb(0 0 0 / 23%);">
            <div class="panel-body Shadows-2 ">
            <!--        ===========        inputs filtre-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                    <label> Date début </label>
                    <input type="date" id="dateMinI" class="form-control" name="dateMinI">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                    <label> Date fin </label>
                    <input type="date" id="dateMaxI" class="form-control" name="dateMaxI" >
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                    <label> N° Document </label>
                    <input type="text" id="Reference" class="form-control" name="Reference" value autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                    <label> Fournisseur </label>
                    <input type="text" id="fournisseur" class="form-control" name="fournisseur" >
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                    <label> Document Type </label>

                    <select id="doctype" class="form-control" name="doctype">
                        <option value="">---</option>

                        <?php foreach ($this->docTypes as $item) : ?>
                            <option value=<?php echo $item->id; ?> >   <?php echo $item->label; ?> </option>
                        <?php endforeach;
                          ?>

                    </select>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class=" padding-20">
                        <button type="button" id="sendid" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                            <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            OK
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
            <!--        ===========        inpouts filtre-->

            <div class="row padding-20 bg-light-grey">

                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#transformerModal" id="transformer"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Transformer
                </button>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                    <button type="button " class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Ajouter <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">


                        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">
                                <i class="   btn-sm fa fa-file-text-o " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                DEVIS</a></li>

                        <li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="/document/add/5">
                                <i class="  btn-light-purple  fa fa-file-text-o btn-sm " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                BON DE COMMANDE</a>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="/document/add/19">
                                <i class="btn btn-green  fa fa-file-text-o btn-sm" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                BON DE LIVRAISON</a>
                        </li>


                        <li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="/document/add/20">
                                <i class=" btn-light-orange  fa fa-file-text-o btn-sm " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                BON DE RETOUR</a>
                        </li>


                        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">
                                <i class="btn btn-light-azure  btn-sm fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                FACTURE INTERNE</a></li>

                        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">
                                <i class="btn  btn-dark-azure  btn-sm fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                FACTURE A COMPTABILISER</a></li>

                        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">
                                <i class="   btn-sm fa fa-file-text-o " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                FACTURE COMPTABILISEE </a></li>

                        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">
                                <i class=" btn-dark-orange  btn-sm fa fa-file-text-o " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                FACTURE DE RETOUR</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="/document/add/33">
                                <i class=" btn-dark-yellow  fa fa-file-text-o btn-sm " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                AVOIR FINANCIER</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        Ajouter
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <?php

                        foreach ($this->docTypes as $item)  { ?>
                            <li><a href="<?= $this->url('documentachat', array('action'=>'add', 'id' => $item->id));?>"><?= $item->label?></a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php  ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

module.config.php

```
<?php

return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Documentachat\Controller\Documentachat' => 'Documentachat\Controller\DocumentachatController',
            'Documentachat\Controller\Parametreachat' => 'Documentachat\Controller\ParametreachatController',
            'Documentachat\Controller\DocArticle' => 'Documentachat\Controller\DocArticleController',
        ),
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'documentachat' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/documentachat[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Documentachat\Controller\Documentachat',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),


            'parametreachat' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/parametreachat[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Documentachat\Controller\Parametreachat',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

            'docarticle' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/docarticle[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Documentachat\Controller\DocArticle',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

        ),
    ),


    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'documentachat' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: You must buffer the `$resultSetPrototype` of the `TableGateway`. I suggest you to do it in `DocumentachatTable` factory

Comment: i wrote this line $resultSetPrototypet->buffer()  in  DocumentachatTable  but without any result, where must i write it in the code?

Comment: As said before, you should add it in the `DocumentachatTable` **factory** ;)

Comment: Table  file is my DocumentachatTable  factory,  i added it enclose my code:   if ($paginated) {
            $select = new Select('achat__document');
            $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
            $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Documentachat());
            $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect(
                $select,
                $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(),
                    $resultSetPrototype->buffer();
                $resultSetPrototype

Comment: Code in comment is unreadable. Update the question with the __full__ code of the factory..

Comment: You can check it in DocumentachatTable factory below .

Comment: That's not the **FACTORY** of `DocumentachatTable`. You must search it in the configuration (normally, in `module.config.php`)

Comment: module.config.php, added, you can check

Comment: There is no factory declaration in your module.config.php, therefore you are doing it somewhere else. I don't know WHERE you are instantiating `DocumentachatTable`, but somewhere you are doing it. Look for that code and then update the question.